# I have no internet access on my laptop. I have a private ip 169.252.x.x

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I have a windows 10 Asus x555lab and I have connectivity issues to both my university network and my home network.  I have a private ip address 169.254.253.110 and no default gateway.  I know this is to do with the DHCP but on two different networks? I have tried restarting everything. Renewing ip address etc

Comment: 169.254.0.0/16 is a link-local (i.e. self-assigned) IP address. Check your DHCP settings. If you're on wireless, try wired, and vice versa.

Comment: Title says 169.252.x.x, question body says 169.254.253.110. Did you mean 169.254.x.x in the title? Note: You can [edit] your question to fix this, and please do. 169.252 is a real, globally routable, assigned IP range (169.252.0.0/15, or 169.252.0.0 through 169.253.255.255, is assigned to the US Department of State as of today).

Answer (score 1):

#### I have no internet access on my laptop

Try reinitialising the network states. Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [ipconfig](http://ss64.com/nt/ipconfig.html) - Configure IP (Internet Protocol configuration)
- [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - Configure Network Interfaces, Windows Firewall, Routing & remote access.
- [route](http://ss64.com/nt/route.html) - Manipulate network routing tables. Route packets of network traffic from one subnet to another by modifying the route table.