# Access denied for every "192.168.x.x" IP address on W7 - works with VPN

Tags: windows-7, networking, router

This is an issue I've had for a while but it's only recently that it's become a problem that's hindering me.

When I attempt to access *any* IP on my network (e.g 192.168.x.x) from my W7 machine I get an access denied error. This applies even to IPs that don't point to anything and even my router.

The only way I'm able to access any other device on my network is, oddly enough, connecting to a VPN, after which it lets me through.

I've tried disabling my Firewall but it didn't do anything.

I've also scoured (after connecting to a VPN so I could actually access it) the settings menu of my router (a BT Home Hub 5) for any settings that could be causing this but I couldn't find anything (it is entirely possible I'm missing something though).

I'm at a complete loss with this. It wasn't always an issue, it used to be just fine, but the issue started so long ago now that I couldn't even fathom a guess as to what might have changed when it started.

Comment: Wireless or Ethernet?

Comment: @DavidPostill Ethernet

Comment: Can you ping the other devices? How are you trying to access them?

Comment: @DavidPostill Trying to ping the devices results in "General failure" errors from the ping command (but works fine when connected to a VPN). When it comes to my router, I try to go through Chrome resulting in ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED (other browsers fail too). The other device I try to access through explorer to get to a network share, but Windows tells me there was an unspecified error (Error code 0x80004005)

Comment: Please follow the instructions in my answer https://superuser.com/a/1190770/337631 and report back with the results

Comment: Is it possible that your router is already connected to this VPN, so without you also connecting to it you are not part of this created network and can't see the other devices, while these devices are automatically connecting to the VPN via the router?

Comment: @DavidPostill I did everything listed in your answer and restarted, but nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: @harrymc I'm fairly confident it's not, the router doesn't seem to have any options to route through a proxy or VPN.

Comment: The other devices seem to be on it. Which VPN is it?

Comment: @harrymc I use NordVPN. It isn't installed on any other device and I'm pretty sure that Nord doesn't mess with your actual router settings

Comment: What is the router?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124548/discussion-between-jill-nesbit-and-harrymc).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the answer was staring me in the face the whole time.

The issue was caused by NordVPN's "Invisible on LAN" option, which clearly states that enabling it will stop you from accessing other devices while not connected. I don't remember enabling this option so I'm not positive if it always mentioned that but after disabling it I can finally connect to other devices on the network again.